# Local hero getting '!_debugDisposed': is not true. exception

Tags: flutter, user-interface

**This is local hero scope which at the parent widget**

```
LocalHeroScope(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                createRectTween: (begin, end) {
                  return RectTween(begin: begin, end: end);
                },
                curve: Curves.easeOut,
                child: Expanded(
                    child:
                        dialPad ? const KeyPadCustom() : const RingDialPad()),
              ),
```

**That's how local hero is used here with the transform widget**

```
Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(
                    (i + 1) * -pi / 6, numberRadiusFromCenter),
                child: LocalHero(
                  tag: "local hero ${Constants.dialPadNumbers[i].toString()}",
                  child: RoundedNumber(
                    number: Constants.dialPadNumbers[i].toString(),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    radius: Constants.dialNumberRadius,
                    style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue().copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

**it's the second widget where I'm using local hero**

```
 LocalHero(
                  tag:
                      "local hero ${Constants.dialPadNumbers[columnIndex].toString()}",
                  child: RoundedNumber(
                    number: Constants.dialPadNumbers[columnIndex].toString(),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    radius: Constants.dialNumberRadius,
                    style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue().copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

getting multiple exceptions as

```
════════ Exception caught by animation library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2803 pos 12: '!_debugDisposed': is not true.
object.dart:2803
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```